# $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ have the same orientation, prove there are at least two equivalence classes.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, equivalence-relations, orientation, jacobian

> Fix a set $W \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and let $k \leq n$. Define
>
> $S_W := \{ \Phi:U \to W: U \subseteq \mathbb R^k $ is open, $\Phi $is a smooth embedding, and$ \Phi(U)=W \}$.
>
> Suppose that $S_W$ is not empty. For $\Phi, \Psi \in S_W$, write $\Phi \sim \Psi$ if $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ have the same orientation.
>
> (i) Show that there are at least two equivalence classes for $\sim$.
>
> (ii) Prove that, if $W$ is connected, then for any $\Phi, \Psi \in S_W$, either $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ have the same orientation or they have the opposite orientation; thus there are exactly two equivalence classes for $\sim$ on $S_W$.

I'm quite stuck on this. I know how to prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, so I assume I would implicate this somehow into proving (i) and (ii).

We know det$(J_{\Psi^{-1}\circ\Phi(a)})>0$ for all $a \in U$ by definition of the same orientation.

Since det$^{-1}(J_{\Psi^{-1}\circ\Phi(a)})=\frac{1}{ det(J_{\Psi^{-1}\circ\Phi(a)})}$ we get det$^{-1}(J_{\Psi^{-1}\circ\Phi(a)})>0$ and the 'having the same orientation' relation is symmetric.

Would I find the determinant of two of the equivalence relations and prove that they are different, hence different equivalence relations? I examined a proof involving vectors and the change of basis formula but I'm unsure how to apply it in this case.

Any help/solutions appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

(i) $(x_1,\dots,x_k)\mapsto\Phi(-x_1,\dots,x_k)$, $x\in\cdots$ has the orientation opposed to $\Phi$.

(ii) $\det(J_{\Psi^{-1}\circ\Phi(x)})$ must be $\ne 0$ for all $x\in U$. If $W$ is connected, $U$ must be connected (by homeomorphism) and this means constant sign: $>0$ or $<0$.

EDIT for (i): aplying the chain rule to $\Xi(x_1,\dots,x_k) = \Phi(-x_1,\dots,x_k)$:
$$J\Xi(x_1,\dots,x_k) = J\Phi(-x_1,\dots,x_k)\pmatrix{
-1&0&0&\cdots&0\cr
 0&1&0&\ddots&0\cr
 0&0&1&\ddots&0\cr
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0\cr
 0&0&\cdots&0&1\cr
}
$$
and
$$
\left|\matrix{
-1&0&0&\cdots&0\cr
 0&1&0&\ddots&0\cr
 0&0&1&\ddots&0\cr
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0\cr
 0&0&\cdots&0&1\cr
}\right| = -1.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can I ask how (i) shows there are at least 2 equivalence classes? Does it have anything to do with the determinant?

Comment: @smallscot, yes. Use simply the chain rule.

Comment: Could you show me how? I'm not sure how to apply it, sorry!

Comment: @smallscot, I will edit my answer tomorrow.